# Caliburn resetting SelectedIndex on ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, caliburn.micro

I have a ComboBox that has is its `ItemsSource` bound to a list of items in my ViewModel as well as `SelectedItem` being bound to a property. I also have another ComboBox that is bound to another list, but that uses `SelectedIndex` instead. When I select an item from the first ComboBox, it changes the contents of the seconds ComboBox, and the property bound to `SelectedIndex` gets set to `-1`, which causes nothing to be selected in the ComboBox.

Why is the `SelectedIndex` property reset to -1, and what can I do to prevent it?

**View**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"></ComboBox>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyArray}" SelectedIndex="{Binding MySelectedIndex}"></ComboBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public List<Foo> MyList { get; set; }
private Foo _mySelectedItem;
public Foo MySelectedItem {
    get { return _mySelectedItem; }
    set {
        if (Equals(value, _mySelectedItem)) return;
        _mySelectedItem = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        MyArray = new [] { "othervalue1", "othervalue2", "othervalue3" };
        NotifyOfPropertychange(() => MyArray);
    }
}
public string[] MyArray { get; set; }
public int MySelectedIndex { get; set; }

public MyViewModel() {
    MyList = new List<Foo> { new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo() };
    MySelectedItem = MyList.First();

    MyArray = new [] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
    MySelectedIndex = 1; // "value2"

    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyList);
}
```

So, selecting something from ComboBox bound to MyList causes MyArray to be built with new values. This causes MySelectedIndex to suddenly have the value `-1`, even though the same indices exist in the new array.

Comment: @dymanoid That was a typo. Fixed it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` is indeed reset because the selected item is cleared out when the `ItemsSource` property is set to a new collection of items.

But you should be able to store the index in a temporary variable and re-assign it after the `ItemsSource` has been updated:

```
public Foo MySelectedItem
{
    get { return _mySelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _mySelectedItem)) return;
        _mySelectedItem = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        int temp = MySelectedIndex;
        MyArray = new[] { "othervalue1", "othervalue2", "othervalue3" };
        NotifyOfPropertychange(() => MyArray);

        SelectedIndex = temp;
        NotifyOfPropertychange(() => SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keeping the currently selected index, then setting it back after refilling the combobox worked just fine. Thanks :)